# I asked and answered a question on how to do something and it was said to be off topic?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, vote-to-close

It said that I didn't follow the help center but not what I violated. I answered with how I solved it so others could come up with better solutions.

Answer (score 4):

[Your question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/4233/15) was off-topic because it wasn't looking for a hackish solution. Buying a cable is not a hack.